# Can accepted votes on these two questions be moved over to /actual/ answers?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Users in question: [yakusha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2190256/yakusha) and [Nikita](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1846616/nikita).

Yesterday I answered this question: [Show first 3 lines in html paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15612747/1317805) to find that over an hour later Nikita posted an incorrect and awful quality answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15613613/1317805) which was almost instantly marked as the accepted answer.

It seems that *yakusha* also posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15543379/1317805) which *Nikita* also answered and despite *yakusha*'s comment this was also almost instantly marked as accepted. A quick Google search seems to return no results for `HTTPFunctions.toMap()` so I'm not even sure if this is a real thing.

Considering *Nikita* has been actively asking questions on SO for 4 months but only started answering (3) questions yesterday, I can only assume *yakusha* and *Nikita* are friends or even the same person.

Comment: And nobody bothered to edit out that block of junk text?

Comment: @Mysticial Hard as it is to believe, it's actually part of the question.

Comment: @J.Steen I should probably get some sleep.

Comment: @Mysticial No, your initial reaction is pretty much spot on. It's what I said when I looked - then I hit edit to see the source, and got what the admittedly bad question actually meant. =)

Comment: Good info there, hence +1. Just one minor note: we can't 'accept' answers for anyone else. (Though deleting an answer, if warranted, would *un*-accept the 'bad' one.)

Comment: Nikita's profile picture is also bit...bit...bit...wrong

Comment: The answer was deleted and the accepted mark was removed from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think anybody other than the OP can or will change the accepted answer, but if something fishy is going on you can always flag one of the questions or answers involved and ask a moderator to take a look. Also, know that there is an automatic process on place to detect questionable voting patterns, so if they keep up the shenanigans they're bound to get caught at some point.

Comment: moderator can change the status of "accepted" answer.

Comment: @raynold we can delete an accepted answer, but we can't accept a different one for someone else (even if they cheated.)

Comment: @Raynold perhaps "can or will" is a better choice of words if mods can but generally won't.

Comment: @Caleb, agree with you, +1

Comment: @Raynold & Caleb: I mistyped; we *can't* do it. Fixed the above comment!

Comment: @AndrewBarber Thanks for the clarification. Changes the sense of my 'or' to the non-exclusive variety, but it still works. :-)

Comment: @AndrewBarber, did you mean you can't delete an accepted answer ?

Comment: @raynold No; we can delete accepted answers; but we cannot modify the 'accepted' status, except by deleting it (which removes it as accepted)

Comment: ok, thanks for updating my knowledge :)

Answer (score 8):

Simple solution for this kind of situation is to just Moderator attention flag. Just flag any of one user's post and choose the "other" option, write second user's profile link and ask moderator to look into it.

Moderator has better view to check all the related details, if they are friends or same person.